# Callback function in Axios returning error (using Vue, no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

I am using Axios with the Vue Javascript framework to loop through an array. I'm trying to set each element in the array to the result of the API call for that element. My functions were not running in order, so I tried using a callback function but it returns an error.

I have looked through other answers(which is why I'm trying to use a callback function) but I still can't get my code to work.

I have a CodePen that shows my problem:

https://codepen.io/thwaawaa/pen/VoEbqR

The CodePen console gives me this error:

```
[object Error] {
  column: 19,
  line: 34,
  sourceURL: “some long link”
}
```

Comment: axios is not defined.

Comment: Sorry try this link: https://codepen.io/thwaawaa/pen/VoEbqR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working fork with no errors : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/WVaENy?editors=1111)

the issue you had is that the `this.word` inside your `then` callback was not defined because you didn't bind the `vue` `this` inside it ...also you handled the response by using 2 `then`s so the first one was handling the response but it wasn't returning anything to the second one that's why `response` was `undefined` to fix this just use one `then` or return a value from one and chain it to the other `then` after it.... i would recommend removing the first one on your `axi` method and add the code inside it on the other `then` also like we said you have to bind `then` and you can do that by replacing :

```js
then(function(response){
  var r = response.data[0].phonetic;
  this.word[x] = r;
})
```

with this :

```js
then((response) => {
  var r = response.data[0].phonetic;
  this.word[x] = r;
})
```

the arrow function will bind the `this` implicitly so your function now knows what `this` means and it won't trigger the `catch`